# Search for IDs from pool of txt files

Tags: python, bash, file, awk

I have asked a one to one query search question, but this one is a one to many files search question. I have one query.txt file containing a thousand IDs.

```
query.txt
GABDI004191
GABDI007217
GABDI004196
GABDI008080
.....
```

And I have a group of files (file1.table, file2.table to file120.table) which contains search hits of individual IDs with other sequences.

```
file1.table
GABDI004191 c23504_g1_i1    29.38   160 100 2   1   160 90  530 
GABDI004191 c20415_g1_i1    45.21   73  39  1   180 252 27  242 
GABDI004191 c17483_g1_i1    88.78   98  11  0   20  117 1   294 
GABDI008080 c1407_g1_i1 95.56   45  2   0   112 156 200 66  9e-25   
GABDI004196 c2892_g1_i1 35.44   79  50  1   37  115 237 4   7e-08

file2.table
GABDI007217 TR9707|c0_g1_i1 32.47   77  49  2   1   77  309 88  
GABDI004196 TR9163|c0_g1_i1 63.77   69  25  0   315 383 207 1   
GABDI007217 TR1165|c0_g1_i1 91.56   154 12  1   1   153 464 3   
GABDI004191 TR4933|c0_g1_i1 91.56   154 12  1   1   153 35  496 
GABDI008080 TR16029|c0_g1_i1    32.20   118 77  2   37  152 242
```

I need to extract for each ID all the lines it appears from each .table files and store them in a separate file that bears the ID's name. for example.

for ID **GABDI008080**, it will have an output file **GABDI008080.txt** which contains the following

```
GABDI008080 c1407_g1_i1 95.56   45  2   0   112 156 200 66  9e-25
GABDI008080 TR16029|c0_g1_i1    32.20   118 77  2   37  152 242
```

and for ID **GABDI004191** it will have an output file **GABDI004191.txt** which will contain the following

```
GABDI004191 c23504_g1_i1    29.38   160 100 2   1   160 90  530 
GABDI004191 c20415_g1_i1    45.21   73  39  1   180 252 27  242 
GABDI004191 c17483_g1_i1    88.78   98  11  0   20  117 1   294
GABDI004191 TR4933|c0_g1_i1 91.56   154 12  1   1   153 35  496
```

I have just started learning Python and Bash scripting.
I tried the following python codes but I got stuck.

```
#!/bin/python
import glob
with open('query.txt' , 'r') as query_file: #reading in IDs from query     file
   for id in query_file:
     for file in glob.glob("*.table"): 
        with open(file, 'r') as one_file: #opening individual files for  reading
           for line in one_file:
              if id in line: #trying to find IDs from each line in those files
                 idname=open(id +'.txt', 'w') #opening a file with the ID name where all found results for that ID is stored
                 idname.append(line)
                 idnam.close()
```

I would appreciate any help please, Using Awk, or whatever Shell script, or Python.
Thanks

Comment: You do not mention how many rows your 120 table files have.

Also, what fraction of all the distinct identifiers do the thousand 
identifier in the query.txt file represent? 

Are the table files sorted by the first column? Can they be? 
The query file is certainly small enough to sort and guarantee unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bash you can do something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  for f in file*.table; do
    grep "^$i " "$f" >> "${i}.txt"
  done
done < query.txt
```

Or even better, since you don't need to know where the lines come from:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  grep "^$i " file*.table >> "${i}.txt"
done < query.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton I was considering copy/paste, but you are right. Changed var name on behalf of clarity. Tks

Comment: Instead of the `for` loop, you can use `grep "^$i " file*.table`

Comment: You'd probably get away with it given this particular input set but you should always use `while IFS= read -r i` in your shell loops unless you have a specific purpose in mind by NOT using `IFS=` or `-r`. Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Comment: Both IFS= and -r are good habits regarding the read builtin command. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In think this should work for you:

**EDIT: corrected code, as it was not working. Now fully functional**

> Explanation: First, I load all the CodeList into an internal array,
>   and then, I print the lines of each file if they are in the code list,
>   and I print them on a file named with each code.

```
cat: awk: No such file or directory
$ ./awk.sh
GABDI004191
GABDI007217
GABDI004196
GABDI008080
$ cat query.txt
GABDI004191
GABDI007217
GABDI004196
GABDI008080
$ cat file1.table
GABDI004191 c23504_g1_i1    29.38   160 100 2   1   160 90  530
GABDI004191 c20415_g1_i1    45.21   73  39  1   180 252 27  242
GABDI004191 c17483_g1_i1    88.78   98  11  0   20  117 1   294
GABDI008080 c1407_g1_i1 95.56   45  2   0   112 156 200 66  9e-25
GABDI004196 c2892_g1_i1 35.44   79  50  1   37  115 237 4   7e-08
$ cat file2.table
GABDI007217 TR9707|c0_g1_i1 32.47   77  49  2   1   77  309 88
GABDI004196 TR9163|c0_g1_i1 63.77   69  25  0   315 383 207 1
GABDI007217 TR1165|c0_g1_i1 91.56   154 12  1   1   153 464 3
GABDI004191 TR4933|c0_g1_i1 91.56   154 12  1   1   153 35  496
GABDI008080 TR16029|c0_g1_i1    32.20   118 77  2   37  152 242
$ cat awk.sh
 awk  'BEGIN{
              while ((getline line < "query.txt" ) > 0)
              {codeList[line]=line
                print codeList[line]
                }
              close("query.txt" )
         }
        $1 in codeList { print $0 > $1".txt"}
'  file*.table
$ ./awk.sh
GABDI004191
GABDI007217
GABDI004196
GABDI008080
$ ls *txt
GABDI004191.txt  GABDI004196.txt  GABDI008080.txt  query.txt
$ cat GABDI004191.txt
GABDI004191 c23504_g1_i1    29.38   160 100 2   1   160 90  530
GABDI004191 c20415_g1_i1    45.21   73  39  1   180 252 27  242
GABDI004191 c17483_g1_i1    88.78   98  11  0   20  117 1   294
$
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next} $1 in ids{print > ($1".txt")}' query.txt *.table
```

If you get an error message about having too many files open concurrently then get/use GNU awk as it handles that for you internally, otherwise if that proves impossible to do then add `close($1".txt")` after the `print...`.

A shell is an environment from which to manipulate (e.g. create/move/destroy) files and processes and sequence calls to tools. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk so any time you need to manipulate text in UNIX you should write an awk script and just call it from your shell. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed, I found the book in awk and I am learning so much already.